# jQuery function breaks when using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contenteditable

I am aiming to use a `contenteditable="true"` div so that I can display the contents of `wp_content` however once this is modified it needs to be submitted via a `<textarea>` I am using the following jQuery in order to update the text area upon any edits in the editable div.

```
jQuery( "#contentEdit" ).keyup(function( event ) {
    value = jQuery('#contentEdit').html();
    jQuery("#myTextarea").val(value);
});
```

And I have the elements that this relates to.

```
<div id="contentEdit" contenteditable="true">
  <h1>some editable content</h1>
</div>                                          
<textarea class="form-control" id="myTextarea" name="Description" rows="3">
  <h1>some editable content</h1>
</textarea>
```

This works fine... However, when I try adding in `<?php the_content(); ?>` or even `echo the_content();` It breaks and I am unable to get the jQuery code to update anything.

An example would be:

```
<div id="contentEdit" contenteditable="true"><?php echo the_content(); ?></div>
```

EDIT: I have got this working perfectly in a new page - it seems that it will not work within a bootstrap modal.

My jquery now looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('keyup','#editableContent',function(){
        value = jQuery('#editableContent').html();
        jQuery("#myTextarea").val(value);
    });
});
```

EDIT2 
Now I know that I need unique IDs I am trying to use the following.

```
var editableID = 'editableContent<?php echo the_ID(); ?>';
var textAreaID = 'myTextarea<?php the_ID();?>';

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('keyup', editableID ,function(){
        value = jQuery(editableID).html();
        jQuery(textAreaID).val(value);
    });
});
```

EDIT 3

I finally got this working using the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#editableContent<?php echo the_ID(); ?>' ,function(){
        value = jQuery('#editableContent<?php echo the_ID(); ?>').html();
        jQuery('#myTextarea<?php echo the_ID(); ?>').val(value);
    });
});
```

Being fairly new to this it would appreciated if someone can optimise this code? and advise me on if this is poor form....

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the `the_content()` function.
Be sure this function does not produces mutliple divs with the same ID

Comment: This is the issue I am working on now DarkBee the search results in this case loop through 20 results creating a unique modal for each one - however they have the same ID of editable area.

This means that it only works on the FIRST result. Would it be good form to ad a unique ID to each editable area from its WP `the_ID`?  if so how would I achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: Thats why it does not work. ID's have to be unique. Try to change up to class and use the `.editableContent`selector after that

Comment: That still only works on the first result...

Comment: why you are using jQuery() where you can simply use $() ?

Comment: I get a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` if not....

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing specific to PHP which would break jQuery.  jQuery's running across the generated HTML from your web server (PHP), and so the issue's your generated HTML.

When you run your app, view the generated HTML source and compare it against your desired HTML template.  I'd bet there are breaking differences between the two (I'm assuming you successfully tested your app with your hand-coded HTML and then tried to abstract that hand-coded HTML in to your `the_content()` PHP function).

To be clear, I'm expecting that the issue is in your `the_content()` function, but I just wanted to point out that whatever problem you're experiencing is from your particular implementation and not because of your architectural decision to use PHP.

Comment: I have noticed that this is not working within a bootstrap modal - Please see edit.